# My windows media center box died. How can I recover my recording schedule?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center

The motherboard in my living room windows media center box was recently fried by a power surge.  This isn't a huge problem because the hardware was old and ready for replacement, plus the hard drive is still fine.  My problem is that I don't remember all of the TV series it had been scheduled to record.  I'd like to examine the old hard drive and view the list of TV series it had been recording so I can enter the shows in to my replacement box.  It would be awesome if this list was stored in an XML file somewhere.  Does anyone out there know where I should look on a standard install of Windows 7 Ultimate?

Comment: please provide us with more information. what have your tried? what does google say? maybe a picture of your file system...

Comment: I have tried googling various questions including "where is windows media center series data stored" none of which return anything useful.  As far as providing a picture of my file system, what does that even mean?  It's a regular install of Win7 Ultimate.  When I tell media center to record a TV series where is the name of that series stored on the hard drive?

Comment: Great! more information. Besides. Google is a wierd beeing. tip google on a word twice in the same qw puts more weight on that word. so 'panncakes panncakes recepie with cheese' = better answers than just 'panncakes recepie with cheese'. P.S. Your box was fried. Bad to hear that. I feel you.